# Objects are not valid as a React child - Cannot resolve error

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I have the following code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

function Test() {
  const [Movie, setMovies] = useState([]);


  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=${APP_KEY_MOVIE}&language=en-US&sort_by=popularity.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1`
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        setMovies(data.results);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h6>Some text here...</h6>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Test;
```

However, I keep getting the following console message and I'm not sure why because it's my first time using functional components with useState hook

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {popularity, vote_count, video, poster_path, id, adult, backdrop_path, original_language, original_title, genre_ids, title, vote_average, overview, release_date}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

This is how the data that is returned is structured:

```
page: 1, total_results: 10000, total_pages: 500, results: Array(20)}
 page: 1
 total_results: 10000
 total_pages: 500
 results: Array(20)
  0: Object
  1: Object
  2: Object
  3: Object
  4: Object
  5: Object
  6: Object
  7: Object
  8: Object
  9: Object
  10: Object
  11: Object
  12: Object
  13: Object
  14: Object
  15: Object
  16: Object
  17: Object
  18: Object
  19: Object
```

I am pretty sure that the state can have an array of objects but I just don't know why this is happening. Please, any assistance is much appreciated!

Comment: You didn't post the code where the error occurs.

Comment: I got the following in the console:

Comment: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {popularity, vote_count, video, poster_path, id, adult, backdrop_path, original_language, original_title, genre_ids, title, vote_average, overview, release_date}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: This is the error. But the code you posted has nothing to do with the error.

Comment: First you need to identify which component cause this error, if you dont have any clues then you can try by removing one by one component to see which one causing errors

Comment: ...or just look at the stack trace on the error!  Probably somewhere in your JSX you are doing this `<div>{movie}</div>` thinking that `movie` is the name when it's actually the whole object.  That error is not in the code you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem is not in this component. According to the error, you are passing into JSX some object (found: an object with keys {popularity, vote_count, ... ). You cant pass plain objects into JSX. Try to verify where you are passing some data into JSX and verify its type. Only strings, numbers, null, boolean, and arrays are allowed, but elements of array should be ReactNode or some primitives

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions thus far however, what I realized is that it works whenever I put the code in a function (without the useEffect) and call the function with an onClickevent. I'm really not sure why that happens.

Answer (score 0):

try this to return an array of objects

```
useEffect(() => {
fetch(
  `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie? 
   api_key=${APP_KEY_MOVIE}&language=en- 
   US&sort_by=popularity.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1`
)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
     let res = data.result
     res = res.map(item => {
        const { ...release_date} = item 
     return {...release_date}
     })
    
    setMovies(res);
    console.log(Movies);
  })
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
},[]);
```